# How to Fix the WordPress Updating Failed and Publishing Failed Errors?

Tags: php, html, css, sql, wordpress

It’s been quite a while since Gutenberg was shoved down our throats. And I know how everyone’s having a love-hate relationship with it.

While it’s tricky to maneuver around the Block editor and create your post or page – something that was dead simple before – what really puts you off is when you hit that blue Publish button after all the hard work and get a red error message in return: “Publishing Failed” or “Updating Failed.”

Can anyone help me out in Fixing the WordPress Updating Failed and Publishing Failed Errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention complete error here. For error you need to turn on debugging in wp-config file.

```
   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

If you need more details you can check [Debugging](https://www.fasstechies.com/how-to-enable-debugging-mode-to-find-an-error/)