# I can't install some plugins in bitnami wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using bitnami to create a wordpress website. When i try to install plugins such as : **Forminator** or **Ninja Forms** the installation fails and this messgae is displayed : **Installation failed: There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.Learn more about debugging in WordPress.**
All my plugins/Themes are up to date and i use **elemntor** if that helps.

I am quite new to this so i don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070861/11986114. It will tell you about your error than place it here.